# Using xgboost in BaggingRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

I need to run `xgboost` in `BaggingRegressor`, I use `xgboost`

```
import xgboost

D_train = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, lab_train)
D_val = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train[test_index], lab_train[test_index])
D_pred =xgboost.DMatrix( X_train[test_index])
D_test = xgboost.DMatrix(X_test)
D_ttest = xgboost.DMatrix(ttest)


xgb_params = dict()
xgb_params["objective"] = "reg:linear"
xgb_params["eta"] = 0.01
xgb_params["min_child_weight"] = 6
xgb_params["subsample"] = 0.7
xgb_params["colsample_bytree"] = 0.6
xgb_params["scale_pos_weight"] = 0.8
xgb_params["silent"] = 1
xgb_params["max_depth"] = 10
xgb_params["max_delta_step"]=2
watchlist = [(D_train, 'train')]
xg = xgboost.Booster()

print('1000')
model = xgboost.train(params=xgb_params, dtrain=D_train, num_boost_round=1000, 
                      evals=watchlist, verbose_eval=1, early_stopping_rounds=20)

y_pred1 = model.predict(D_ttest)
```

how to use all the same parameters, but in `BaggingRegressor`?

If I do

```
gdr = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator= xgboost.train( params=xgb_params,
dtrain=D_train,
num_boost_round=3000,
evals=watchlist,
verbose_eval=1,
early_stopping_rounds=20))
```

then the `xgboost` training starts, and then the code

```
gdr_model = gdr
print(gdr_model)
gdr_model.fit(X_train, lab_train)
train_pred = gdr_model.predict(X_test)

print('mse from log: ', mean_squared_error(lab_train, train_pred))

train_pred = gdr_model.predict(ttest)
```

Does not make sense, or am I wrong? tell me how to fix this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xgboost has a [Sklearn](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) wrapper. Try using the following template!

```
import xgboost
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor

X,y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

reg = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=XGBRegressor())

reg.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: that is, in xgboost and XGBRegressor there is no difference? the second is just a shell, right?

Comment: yes, Xbgoost and XGBRegressor are the same. can you detail you second question? I did not get it

Comment: inattentively read the answer, you have already answered the second question "Xgboost has a Sklearn wrapper."